# C#/ASP.net classes uml diagram

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can somebody explain this to me? How it would work and what it does. I am creating a c# student registration form.

[image]

I created my class:

```
public class Course
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Just confused on the list part and what it does....

Comment: We would need to see the class diagram.

Comment: how can i attach the image here? new to this lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to think in an object oriented paradigm.  Your course will have the following:

- Number (Id)
- Name
- List Of Students (Collection)

Based on the following description, your model isn't complete.  As I indicated above, think in an object oriented paradigm.  If I have a school, *how would I govern the courses and students?*

```
public class Student : IEntity<int>
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Course : IEntity<int>
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The initial foundation exist, for every course I'll have a collection of students enrolled in the course.  That would be the foundation, to build upon the example though:

1. How would the model change, if I have to track courses by school?
2. How would the model change, if I need to append a numeric grade for a student?

These questions, will impact your model's.  As I denoted above, if you think in the paradigm of objects and how they relate together it will help you build your initial objects but the relational data tables in the database as well.

Also, without the entire diagram we would be assuming or inferring our own interpretation, hopefully this will assist you.